How to mock an internal import in Deno?
Say I have module utils that imports module logger. I am about to write unit tests for module utils and I want to mock logger when logger is being tested.
// utils.ts

import logger from "logger";

export function add(j: number, k: number) {
    logger.log(`Adding ${j} and ${k}`);
    return j + k;
}

// logger.ts

export default {
    log: (msg: string) => console.info(msg),
}

// utils.test.ts

import { assertEquals } from "@std/assert";
import { add } from "../src/utils.ts";

Deno.test(function testAdd() {
    assertEquals(add(1, 2), 3);
});

I understand it's possible to use import maps (see this), but I found out I have to manually copy all my dependencies from deno.json into the import map. For example, this is the deno.json file for this example:
{
  "imports": {
    "@std/assert": "jsr:@std/assert@^1.0.6",
    "logger": "./src/logger.ts"
  }
}

My import map needs to look like this:
{
  "imports": {
    "@std/assert": "jsr:@std/assert@^1.0.6",
    "logger": "./logger-stub.ts"
  }
}

Notice that I need to specify @std/assert. If I don't, Deno won't be able to resolve it because the import map completely overrides the list in deno.json.
This is bad because every time I add a dependency in my project, I need to manually update the import map. It doesn't look like import maps are the best solution for mocking modules.
I looked for other solutions to this problem, but I found none. Note that I could be using dependency injection, but something like a logger is a cross-cutting concern in an application, meaning that virtually all modules will need to inject it. I'd rather prefer not doing it if I could.
So the question is: are there alternatives to mock logger in the example above?

This question is similar to: Deno mock out named import in unit test. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jsejcksn thanks. I did read that answer before posting mine, but it goes in a different direction, using import maps to solve the problem. As stated in my question, import maps were not created with mocking in mind and do not solve the problem well. Edited to add a link to that question.
